# SOX fade not as expected

Tags: sox

I am using sox to fade in and out.

```
sox input.wav output.wav fade 0.5 0 0.5
```

However, rather than fading in a linear fashion from the start of the audio, sox is muting some audio then doing a much quicker fade:
[image: Image of Sox fade]

This is how I would expect the fade to look (mock-up not to scale):
[image: Correct fade]

Any thoughts? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out for myself:

```
sox input.wav output.wav fade t 0.5 0 0.5
```